# Part of speech of "one day"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the part of speech of "one day" in the following sentences? And Why don’t we use articles with it?

> - **One day** a boy started teasing Grady.
> - A lion was asleep in the sun **one day**.

Comment: "One day" plays the role of an adverb, like "today."

Comment: "One day" is a noun phrase consisting of the determinative "one" and the noun "day". The phrase is functioning as an adjunct of time. Since "one" is a determiner marking the phrase as indefinite, there's no need for another determiner like an article.